# Easy way to overwrite basic jQuery-UI css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I feel like this is a silly question but I always find that modifying certain CSS attributes to be a hassle when working with jQuery. Let's say I define an element as a jQuery-UI object (like autocomplete or the datepicker) how do I go about modifying the CSS without having to go on the UI site and building my own theme?

For example, I find that the default font-size of the calendar to be pretty big so I often have to find the containing div created by jQuery and then add a `font-size: 14px !important;` if I want the style to be applied or else it gets trumped by the jQuery definition (since it's a lot more selective).

Is the solution making my rules more selective or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: I sympathize. I honestly respect jQuery UI but I think it's a really bad solution for a lot of sites exactly because of the layout it imposes. What I've done is just taken the CSS they gave me and freely modified it. A lot. I really don't want my site to look like a "jQuery UI site" anyway, and I have no regrets :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not used JQuery-UI, but a quick look at their documentation seems to indicate that a lot of styling should be simple to override. This page http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API talks about your particular example of `font-size`, stating that the `.ui-widget` class controls the `font-size` for a particular widget. So it seems like for you to get your font size, you would just need to have some css that does this:

```
#ui-datepicker-div.ui-widget {font-size: 14px}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow great link, thanks! I always looked in the css that comes with the download and it always seems like they have a mile-long selector so I figured it was so much more complicated than this :)

Comment: The page linked above has gone now (in 2014), try here: http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/