# Overwrite basic jQuery-UI css for ui-tabs does not work

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website that uses jquery tabs+standard ui theme, and I'd like to change/override the font settings (size) of the ui theme. Though I looked at related sites [Easy way to overwrite basic jQuery-UI css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290831/easy-way-to-overwrite-basic-jquery-ui-css), http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/, http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/ I cant get it worked.

Pls your help.

Here's what I have now (simplified code):

```
<style>
  #ui-tabs-div.ui-widget {font-size: 10px} /* this is not working */
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" >    </script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  }
</script>

<div id="tabs"> </div> <!--tab contents here -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AHXwv/

```
 #tabs.ui-widget {font-size: 10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an ID before the class to overwrite the default css:

```
#myId .ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
```

}

Comment: thnx. I assume myId should be 'tabs' in my case as also suggested by arun (?)